# How to use a variable as a key inside object initialiser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In the application I am working, the server pages are used to recieving an input's name as the key for it's value. Is is possible to do this with ajax? 
In this example, thisName is treated as a literal string.

```
$('table').each(function(){ 
    $(this).delegate("input", "focusout", function(){
        var thisValue = $(this).val();
        var thisName = $(this).attr('name');
        $.ajax({
            timeout: 3000,
            //cache: false,
            data: {
                p_session_id: $("[name='p_session_id']").val(),
                p_username: $("[name='p_username']").val(), 
                thisName: thisValue
//              ^^
            },
            success: function(data){
            alert( data )
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Try data: {p_session_id: $("[name='p_session_id']").val(), p_username: $("[name='p_username']").val(), (thisName): thisValue}, i.e. `(thisName): thisValue`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, inside an object initialiser the part on the left side of the `:` is not treated as a variable but as a string, so `the_key` is regarded the same as `"the_key"`.

This is the most straightforward way I can think of to add properties with a dynamic name:

```
var fields = {
    p_session_id: $("[name='p_session_id']").val(),
    p_username: $("[name='p_username']").val()
}
fields[thisName] = thisValue;
```

Then use `fields` in your `$.ajax` call as `data: fields`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not quite as elegant but :

```
function makeObj (a) {
  if (!(a instanceof Array))
    throw ('Attempt to build object from ' + (typeof a));
  if (a.length % 2)  
    throw ('Attempt to build object from an array length ' + a.length);

  for (var o = {}, i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i -= 2) {
    console.log (a[i-1], a[i]); 
    o[a[i - 1]] = a[i];
  }  
  return o;
}

var thisName = 'Hans PUFAL';
var thisValue = 'Paleoinformaticien';
var session_id = '123edrft456fg';

var o = makeObj (['p_session_id', session_id,
              'p_username', 'HBP',
              thisName, thisValue]);
```

Available here : http://jsfiddle.net/jstoolsmith/bZtpQ