# Key for javascript dictionary is not stored as value but as variable name

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a dictionary object like so

```
var obj = { varName : varValue };
```

What I'm expecting is if `varName='foo'`, the obj should be `{'foo', 'some value' }` however what I see is `{varName, 'some value'}` the value of variable is not being used but a variable name as a key. How do I make it so that varible value is used as key?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use a variable as a key inside object initialiser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631007/how-to-use-a-variable-as-a-key-inside-object-initialiser)

Answer (score 201):

Try like this:

```
var obj = {};
obj[varName] = varValue;
```

You can't initialize objects with 'dynamic' keys in old Javascript. `var obj = { varName : varValue };` is equivalent to `var obj = { "varName" : varValue };`. This is how Javascript interprets.

However new ECMAScript supports [*computed property names*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names), and you can do:

```
var obj = { [varName]: varValue };
```

Comment: This works! Thanks. Although I'm still curious why the other way doesn't work.

Comment: Because generally when you're constructing objects with a fixed set of keys (which is what the `{}` syntax is doing) you know what those keys are. The alternative would require everyone who _does_ want fixed keys to put quotes around them, which would be more work for more people more of the time.

Comment: You might also see this question I just answered : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631007/how-to-use-a-variable-as-a-key-inside-object-initialiser

Answer (score 54):

Starting with ECMAScript 2015, which has gotten better browser support in the last year(s), you can use the variable index notation:

```
const obj = { [varName] : varValue };
```

This is syntactically the same as

```
var obj = {};
obj[varName] = varValue;
```

You can also use expressions or Symbols as property key:

```
const contact = {
    company: companyName,
};
const companiesWithContacts = {
    [contact.company.toLowerCase()]: true
};
```

```
const myList = {
    [Symbol.iterator]: createIteratorForList
};
function createIteratorForList() { ... }
```