# Display the value of a variable in a javascript code

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc

I have a variable in my js code that i want to display its `value` in js code but always get the `name` of the variable not the `value`

Here is the variable

```
var aa = '<c:out value="${listevennementfuture}"/>';
```

This is where I want the `value` to be displayed in the place of `'aa'`

```
$(".responsive-calendar").responsiveCalendar({
          time: today,
          events:  aa                  });
```

How can I solve this? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the quotes around the variable i.e change `var aa = '<c:out value="${listevennementfuture}"/>';` to `var aa = <c:out value="${listevennementfuture}"/>;`

You could also try a cleaner approach like

1. add your JSP variable to an HTML element's data-* attribute
2. then read this value via Javascript when required

Comment: I removed the quotes then replaced **aa** the one after **events:** by **<c:out value="${listevennementfuture}" escapeXml="false"/>** that did the trick, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

[Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640159/key-for-javascript-dictionary-is-not-stored-as-value-but-as-variable-name).

You need to declare an empty object and assign the values after.

```
var obj = {};
obj['events'] = aa;
```

Comment: If you try `obj['events'] = aa;` instead, does it work?