# How can i name object "keys" programmatically in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

What i want is something i do every day in Python. In JS it does not work, most probably because i suck in JS.

This is the Python code that would do what i want:

```
>key = 'just_a_key'
>value = 5
>dict = {key: value}
>dict
{'just_a_key':5}
>dict['just_a_key'}
5
```

This does not work in JS, the key there will be just named 'key'. I know this is because i'm not really creating a dictionary here, but using json to create an object when i write the same code. So my question now is: How can i programmatically name the objects "keys" (or properties?) in JS?

Comment: See this question I have just answered : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631007/how-to-use-a-variable-as-a-key-inside-object-initialiser

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Like this:

```
dict = {};

dict[key] = value;
```

JavaScript does not evaluate expressions for property names in its object literal notation, but it does if you use the square bracket form of the object member operator.

[MDN Member Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators)

Answer (score 16):

*Update*: this answer was originally written in 2012, but there's a better way now using ES2015/ES6 [Computed Property Names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names). The previous example (see below) could now be written as follows:

```
const key = 'just_a_key';

const obj = { [key]: 5 };
```

If you're unfamiliar with object-literal syntax in JavaScript, please note that the important aspect here is the brackets around the dynamic key name (i.e., `[key]`). The brackets indicate that `key` (or any other contents) should be interpreted as an expression, rather than being used as a literal value.

---

Original answer / pre-ES6 solution:

```
var obj = {},
    key = 'just_a_key';

obj[key] = 5;
```