# Unexpected token { when add object to an array with .map

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, dictionary

```
var $scope={};
var componentsDir="/root/";
var appPrefix="/app/";


var scriptRef=[];
function proDir(scriptName){
    return componentsDir+appPrefix+'-home-components/pro/js/'+scriptName+'.js';
};

var scriptList =[
            {s_name:'jquery',file:"jquery.js"},
            {s_name:'bootstrap',file:"bootstrap.min.js"},
            {s_name:'easing',file:"jquery.easing.min.js"},
            {s_name:'fittext',file:"jquery.fittext.js"},
            {s_name:'wow',file:"wow.min.js"},
            {s_name:'creative', file:"creative.js"},

            /*{bootstrap :"bootstrap.min.js"},
            {easing :"jquery.easing.min.js"},
            {fittext :"jquery.fittext.js"},
            {wow :"wow.min.js"},
            {creative :"creative.js"},*/
        ]



var newscript = scriptList.map(function(scriptItem){
    console.log(scriptItem)
    return {{scriptItem.s_name:'jquery'},{scriptItem.file:proDir(scriptItem.file)}},
});

console.log(newscript)
```

I try to find a way to loop through a list of script and add extra dir info to each element with `.map`. But I am getting an error of

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

I try to return each element as a object for the new `newscript` array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{` is not a valid character after `{` in JSON.

replace this line:

```
return {{scriptItem.s_name:'jquery'},{scriptItem.file:proDir(scriptItem.file)}}
```

with this line:

```
return {"scriptItem.s_name": 'jquery', "scriptItem.file": proDir(scriptItem.file)}
```

or another variant might be:

```
return {
    scriptItem: {
        s_name: 'jquery',
        file: proDir(scriptItem.file)
    }
};
```

Here is the variant you asked for with your comment *"I want to access the newscript's location value like this : **newscript.jquery**"*:

```
var newscript = scriptList.map(function(scriptItem) {
    var returnval = {};
    returnval[ scriptItem.s_name ] = scriptItem.file;
    return returnval;
});
```

I think you are bumping up against this issue:

[How can i name object "keys" programmatically in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640479/how-can-i-name-object-keys-programmatically-in-javascript)

When in doubt:

http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: now there is the error of "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ."

Comment: @Chen i updated the answer to fix that. the problem was that keys with special characters need to be quoted

Comment: But I want to access the newscript's location value like this : newscript.jquery       then I go the dir location. instead, now I have to do newscript[0].file. I did change the return into return { [name] :file}, but still I have to do newscript[0].jquery. I wonder if I could just eliminate the [0] and use some how, 'jquery' as the index? Thanks

Comment: ah, i now understand what you're after. I updated the answer. Check the last variant. The trick lies in using bracket notation for your javascript objects, which allows you to evaluate statements when setting keys.

Answer (score 0):

The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.

This means that the scriptItem variable in each map iteration is one of the objects you have in your scriptList array. Map() makes an operation on that variable, and returns a new variable that will be pushed in a new array, that scriptItem will point to.

In your code, you are returning 2 objects, instead of one. But each array element can hold only one object. So, return only one thing.

```
var newscript = scriptList.map(function(scriptItem){
    console.log(scriptItem)
    return {s_name:'jquery', file:proDir(scriptItem.file)}
});
```

Comment: P.S. Official documentation is your best friend :)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work for you:

```
var newscript = scriptList.map(function(scriptItem){
    console.log(scriptItem);
    var name = scriptItem.s_name;
    var file = proDir(scriptItem.file);
    return {s_name: name, file:file}
});
```