# JavaScript set anonymous Object key to variable name

Tags: javascript

```
    var curr = data[i],
        newArray = [],
        key = curr.Frequency.Type,
        obj = {key: []};
    newArray.push(obj);
```

However, this yields an object with a key of "key"! How can I create a new object with a key of the value of the variable `key`?

Comment: This is a very frequently asked question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Key for javascript dictionary is not stored as value but as variable name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640159/key-for-javascript-dictionary-is-not-stored-as-value-but-as-variable-name)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use a variable as a key inside object initialiser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631007/how-to-use-a-variable-as-a-key-inside-object-initialiser)

Comment: Here's one that's even older: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15960027/497418

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var curr = data[i],
    newArray = [],
    key = curr.Frequency.Type,
    obj = {};

obj[key] = [];
newArray.push(obj);
```

There's no way to do it in JavaScript within the object literal itself; the syntax just doesn't provide for that.

*edit* — when this answer was written, the above was true, but ES2015 provides for dynamic keys in object initializers:

```
var curr = data[i],
    key = curr.Frequency.Type,
    newArray = [ { [key]: [] } ];
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean this notation:

```
var type = "some type";
var obj = {}; // can't do it one line
obj[type] = [];
console.log(obj); // { "some type": [] }
```

Answer (score 1):

simply instantiate a new anonymous object from a function.

```
obj = new function () {
    this[key] = [];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is an old question but for those finding this through Google the way to do this with ES6+ is to use square bracket notation in the object literal:

```
const key = 'dynamicKey';
const value = 5;

const objectWithDynamicKey = {
  staticKey: 'another value',
  [key]: value 
}
console.log(objectWithDynamicKey)
```

Which prints:

```
{ 
  staticKey: 'another value', 
  dynamicKey: 5
}
```

So your example should be:

```
var curr = data[i];
var newArray = [];
var key = curr.Frequency.Type;
var obj = { [key]: [] };
newArray.push(obj);
```